# Installing a kernel rpm package in Qubes OS complains: dracut-install: ERROR: installing '/usr/lib64/plymouth//label.so'

Tags: linux-kernel, rpm, qubes

```
$ sudo dnf install kernel-latest-4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64.rpm kernel-latest-devel-4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64.rpm
Qubes OS Repository for Dom0                                                                     25 MB/s |  26 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                Version                                   Repository                 Size
================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel-latest                    x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                 @commandline               13 M
Upgrading:
 kernel-latest-devel              x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                 @commandline               11 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package
Upgrade  1 Package

Total size: 25 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Upgrading   : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        1/3 
  Installing  : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              2/3 
  Cleanup     : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-7.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        3/3 
dracut-install: ERROR: installing '/usr/lib64/plymouth//label.so'
dracut: FAILED: /usr/lib/dracut/dracut-install -D /var/tmp/dracut.qdDWTG/initramfs -a /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/57-dejavu-sans.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/57-dejavu-sans.conf /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /usr/lib64/plymouth//label.so
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              1/3 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        2/3 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-7.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        3/3 

Installed:
  kernel-latest.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                                                                                

Upgraded:
  kernel-latest-devel.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                                                                          

Complete!
```

**What's the package that I need to install so that `label.so` exists and the above doesn't fail?**

I tried to find all possible package names containing `plymouth` in their name:

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ rpm -qa \*plymo\*
plymouth-0.9.3-0.6.20160620git0e65b86c.fc25.x86_64
plymouth-scripts-0.9.3-0.6.20160620git0e65b86c.fc25.x86_64
plymouth-core-libs-0.9.3-0.6.20160620git0e65b86c.fc25.x86_64

[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo dnf search \*plymo\*
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:39 ago on Thu Sep  6 13:53:26 2018.
===================================================== N/S Matched: *plymo* =====================================================
plymouth-scripts.x86_64 : Plymouth related scripts
plymouth-core-libs.x86_64 : Plymouth core libraries
plymouth.x86_64 : Graphical Boot Animation and Logger

$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/plymouth/label.so
error: file /usr/lib64/plymouth/label.so: No such file or directory
```

But this seems to list only the already installed ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is installing `plymouth-plugin-label`:

```
$ sudo qubes-dom0-update plymouth-plugin-label
...
Installed:
  plymouth-graphics-libs.x86_64 0.9.3-0.6.20160620git0e65b86c.fc25                                                              
  plymouth-plugin-label.x86_64 0.9.3-0.6.20160620git0e65b86c.fc25
```

Testing if solution works(it does):

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo dnf reinstall kernel-latest-4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64.rpm kernel-latest-devel-4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64.rpm
Qubes OS Repository for Dom0                                                                     25 MB/s |  26 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                Version                                   Repository                 Size
================================================================================================================================
Reinstalling:
 kernel-latest                    x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                 @commandline               13 M
 kernel-latest-devel              x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                 @commandline               11 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================

Total size: 25 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Reinstalling: kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        1/4 
  Reinstalling: kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              2/4 
  Erasing     : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        3/4 
  Erasing     : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              4/4 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              1/4 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        2/4 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              3/4 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        4/4 

Reinstalled:
  kernel-latest.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes              kernel-latest-devel.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes             

Complete!
```

Looks like the way to search for packages containing the text `plymo` from dom0 is:

```
$ sudo qubes-dom0-update --action=search \*plymo\*
Using sys-firewall as UpdateVM to download updates for Dom0; this may take some time...
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:21 ago on Thu Sep  6 13:58:49 2018.
======================= Summary & Name Matched: *plymo* ========================
plymouth-scripts.x86_64 : Plymouth related scripts
plymouth-core-libs.x86_64 : Plymouth core libraries
plymouth-core-libs.i686 : Plymouth core libraries
plymouth-plugin-label.x86_64 : Plymouth label plugin
plymouth-theme-solar.x86_64 : Plymouth "Solar" theme
plymouth-system-theme.x86_64 : Plymouth default theme
plymouth-theme-charge.x86_64 : Plymouth "Charge" plugin
plymouth-theme-script.x86_64 : Plymouth "Script" plugin
plymouth-theme-breeze.x86_64 : Breeze theme for Plymouth
plymouth-plugin-script.x86_64 : Plymouth "script" plugin
plymouth-theme-fade-in.x86_64 : Plymouth "Fade-In" theme
plymouth-theme-spinner.x86_64 : Plymouth "Spinner" theme
plymouth-graphics-libs.i686 : Plymouth graphics libraries
plymouth-graphics-libs.x86_64 : Plymouth graphics libraries
plymouth-plugin-two-step.x86_64 : Plymouth "two-step" plugin
plymouth-theme-hot-dog.noarch : Plymouth Happy Hot Dog Theme
plymouth-theme-spinfinity.x86_64 : Plymouth "Spinfinity" theme
plymouth-plugin-throbgress.x86_64 : Plymouth "Throbgress" plugin
plymouth-plugin-space-flares.x86_64 : Plymouth "space-flares" plugin
plymouth-plugin-fade-throbber.x86_64 : Plymouth "Fade-Throbber" plugin
plymouth-devel.i686 : Libraries and headers for writing Plymouth splash plugins
plymouth-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and headers for writing Plymouth splash
                      : plugins
============================ Name Matched: *plymo* =============================
plymouth.x86_64 : Graphical Boot Animation and Logger
No packages downloaded
Last metadata expiration check: 0:12:45 ago on Thu Sep  6 13:53:26 2018.
===================================================== N/S Matched: *plymo* =====================================================
plymouth-scripts.x86_64 : Plymouth related scripts
plymouth-core-libs.x86_64 : Plymouth core libraries
plymouth.x86_64 : Graphical Boot Animation and Logger
```

Full details here: https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-linux-kernel/pull/22#issuecomment-419071786

Double-checking that the solution works(it does):

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo dnf remove kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64 kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                Version                                  Repository                  Size
================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 kernel-latest                    x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                @@commandline               63 M
 kernel-latest-devel              x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                @@commandline               44 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================
Remove  2 Packages

Installed size: 107 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Erasing     : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        1/2 
  Erasing     : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              2/2 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              1/2 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        2/2 

Removed:
  kernel-latest.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes              kernel-latest-devel.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes             

Complete!
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo dnf install kernel-latest-4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64.rpm kernel-latest-devel-4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64.rpm
Qubes OS Repository for Dom0                                                                     25 MB/s |  26 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                Version                                   Repository                 Size
================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel-latest                    x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                 @commandline               13 M
 kernel-latest-devel              x86_64              1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes                 @commandline               11 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================
Install  2 Packages

Total size: 25 M
Installed size: 107 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Installing  : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              1/2 
  Installing  : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        2/2 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-devel-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                        1/2 
  Verifying   : kernel-latest-1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes.x86_64                                                              2/2 

Installed:
  kernel-latest.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes              kernel-latest-devel.x86_64 1000:4.18.5-8.pvops.qubes             

Complete!
```